# Comparing factor structure to network analysis using a community detection algorithm

Tags: r, factor-analysis, networks

I am interested in the use of weighted correlational network analysis to explore high dimensional data, instead of latent variable models like exploratory factor analysis (EFA).

My approach is to:

1. Conduct an EFA on the correlation matrix and attain the factor structure.
2. Build the correlational network
3. Filter the correlation network for values only above, e.g. 0.3, to gain some structure
4. Conduct a community detection algorithm (e.g. Infomap: http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1062)
5. Compare the membership of nodes based on the EFA to node membership based on the CD    algorithm using, for example, an ERGM model that specifies node membership and predicts the odds of a tie/triangle forming

But, in this scenario, is the community detection algorithm and the factor structure directly comparable? I know that the community detection algorithm is being based on a different set of correlations to the factor structure (i.e. above .3 or some threshold only) but, apart from this, would this be a viable method of comparing the usefulness of the two methods?

It would be great to get some second opinions. thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should look at http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0051558